# Brand new to signalr

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to get an idea of how signalr works so I'm trying to send a message through the browser, to the hub and back to the browser.

So far I have these three classes

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Monitoring</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var chat = $.connection.MyHub;
        $.connection.hub.start();
        chat.server.sendMessageToWeb("hi", "hello");
        chat.client.getData = function (name,message){
            window.alert(name);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace test
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
{

    public void sendMessageToWeb(String senderName, String message)
    {
        Clients.All.getData(senderName, message);
    }



}
}
```

Owin Startup:

```
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Owin;
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
    namespace SignalRChat
    {
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that the webpage loads and is just blank and doesn't display anything.

Comment: Check any console error in browser

Comment: Are you running in debugger or deployed?

Comment: Try to capitalize SendMessageToWeb only in hub I think it's just convention